# HighCharts: How to read the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, highcharts

This is my JSON:

```
  [{"name":"AniSig01",
    "data":[["2013,06,11,16,06,55",14],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,00",14],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,06",15],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,11",14]]},
   {"name":"AniSig02",
    "data":[["2013,06,11,16,06,55",0],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,00",0],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,06",0],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,11",0]]},
   {"name":"AniSig03",
    "data":[["2013,06,11,16,06,55",6],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,00",6],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,06",7],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,11",6]]},
   {"name":"AniSig04",
    "data":[["2013,06,11,16,06,55",13],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,00",13],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,06",14],
            ["2013,06,11,16,07,11",13]]}]
```

And my HighCharts code:

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
      var options =
      {
         chart:
         {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type: 'spline',
         },
         title:
         {
             text: 'Statistik',
         },
         xAxis:
         {
            type:'datetime',
         },
         yAxis:
         {
             title: { text: ''},
         },
         tooltip:
         {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true,
         },
         plotOptions:
         {
            series:
            {
               marker: {enabled: false},
               animation: false,
               threshold: null
            }
         },
         series:[]
      };

  $.getJSON('datgen/DatReq.txt',function(data)
  {
     $.each(data, function(key,value)
     {
        var series = { data:[]};
        $.each(value, function(key,val)
        {
           if (key == 'name')
           {
              series.name = val;
           }
           else
           {
              $.each(val, function(key,val)
              {
                 val[0] = 'Date.UTC(' + val[0] + ')';
                 series.data.push(val[0], val[1]);
              });
           }
        });
       options.series.push(value);
     });

  var linechart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
  });
```

But I see these 4 signals only as a point (vertical line) on the chart.
and the Tooltip didn't show the correct time (the x-value)!

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Have no idea what "HighChart" is, but spend 5-10 minutes looking at json.org, to understand the JSON syntax better.

Comment: Do you have a http://www.jsFiddle.net ? It would be easier for us to understand and to help you point the problem.

Comment: Is it a point, or is it a line? It cannot be both. What x value (time) _did_ you see? This problem screams broken time parsing. Check your time parsing.

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, your X values are at fault. Not only are they wrong (per the tooltip), but they seem to be the *same* wrong for each point (giving you a vertical line).

So, let's concentrate on the X values. What are they? Okay, times. At some point, you had to parse the times from the data source into Javascript. Where did you do that?

Here:

```
val[0] = 'Date.UTC(' + val[0] + ')';
```

There we go — Javascript functions simply don't work that way. You can't just shove code into a string and expect it to be executed.

Split `val[0]` on the comma character, and feed each part of the result into a *real* call to `Date.UTC`.